# skype on linux mint 15 cannot be installed

Tags: linux, help-files

When I try to install skype with

```
sudo dpkg -f skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

I get this error message

```
dpkg: error processing skype (--install)
```

Then I try

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and try the first commmand again, but I just get the same error.

Comment: Skype retired many versions to prepare for a change in architecture. If this is the case the source files have probably been removed to prevent you from installing something that doesn't work.  http://blogs.skype.com/2014/06/20/making-way-for-the-next-generation-of-skype-on-desktop/

Answer (score 0):

Try to download `multiarch` version instead.

You might have 64bit version of your Mint